# Rack PDU with IP control and surge protection

Tags: rack, power-distribution-unit, surge-protection

Im speccing up a new 16A PDU for a 42u rack build, i need a PDU with IP control so that i can power cycle devices remotely. But I've noticed that most PDUs with IP control don't have surge protection on them.

I can find lots of surge protected PDUs but they tend to be "rack mounted surge protected extension leads" rather than IP controllable PDUs.

Any idea why this is ?

My thought was that i could get a IEC PDU, IP, but non surge and then plug some IEC surge protected "rack mounted extension lead type PDU" something like [THIS](https://www.comms-express.com/products/pdu-with-uk-13amp-plug-sockets/?4~Way?IEC~C14?Yes). But if i did that although the equipment in the rack would be surge protected, the IP controllable PDU wouldn't be.

Comment: Will there be no battery backup system that also regulates the power involved? That's where a lot of racks get their power regulation from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a whole lot of "it depends" on this one.  In most cases involving a managed PDU, suppression is handled upstream somewhere.

If you are in a colo I would recommend talking to their power guys there to get their recommendation.  You may have plenty surge suppression already.

If you will just be plugging these into your own UPSes I would follow the manaufacturer's recommendations.  Some specifically warn against adding suppression on the load (output) side.  Some have suppression built in.  Contact your UPS vendor.

Comment: If a PDU has surge protection built in, I probably wouldn't purchase it, adding complexity increases the number of "moving parts" and increases the likelihood of failure, protection should be from a UPS.